# Javascript error: Slide(function) undefined

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is get the Slide function to work - its passing the CurrenPage data, but the PanelScroller is not updating. Could I possibly have a conflict with some of the other JS libraries / scripts I'm using?

please see http://www.deepwater.nu/simonev

Comment: A quick glance at your page source shows that you've got some jQuery executing in the head without being wrapped in a document.ready(), so that might be part of your problem.

Comment: In fact, those lines as wrapped in `$(function() {});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `function Slide( control, panel ){ ... }` you are setting `top` as `Number` but it should be units (px)

```
PanelScroller.style.top = CurrentPageTop + 'px';
```

To avoid such problems in future i suggest start using jQuery's functions as [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/). After all you've loaded and used it several times already.